# SQL Server 2008 Sql snippets

Tags: sql-server-2008, code-snippets

I think that this is a relatively simple question.  I just want to know if you are able to save or use SQL snippets like you can in Visual Studio, but within SQL Server Management Studio?  I've had a browse but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragging a [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179334.aspx) item into the current query is handy (You can create your own & "file" them in their own hierarchy), and the [SMSS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=0)  addin provides a Snippet function.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant find.  Thanks so much.